# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'xxx'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW);

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have added new fields to model and tried "python manage.py makemigrations" . It gave me below error. Can anyone help me?

**model added**

pm_comments = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True,verbose_name='PM Comments')
archived = models.BooleanField(default=False,blank=True,verbose_name='Archived')

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'pm_comments'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'archived'. (207)")

Comment: makemigrations and then migrate. LEt me know if it worked!

Comment: makemigrations is not successful which is giving me above error

Comment: Can you update your question with the model changes you made?

Comment: What about the column `archived`?

Comment: Useful reading for making your question answerable: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't run the migration you created with

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: makemigrations cmd giving me this error. if it is successfully ran, i can run above command